# Getting 405 error when posting a file in dotnet webapi 5

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Getting 405 error while trying to test my api using swagger. My api accepts data as the following format.

```
 [HttpPost("AddEmployee")]
  public IActionResult AddEmployee(EmployeeDto employee, IFormFile file )
   {

   }
```

**Response getting**

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
  "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
  "status": 415,
  "traceId": "00-19508b3749296a4bb84e43b5d21dc6c7-cabb1ff5b2609a43-00"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, in asp.net core web api if you don't set the `[FromForm]`, it will just accept the json format request.

So I suggest you could set the `[FromForm]` for each parameter like below:

```
[HttpPost("AddEmployee")]
  public IActionResult AddEmployee([FromForm]EmployeeDto employee, [FromForm]IFormFile file )
   {

   }
```

But for the swagger, it couldn't set the right parameter if the web api paramaters contains the model and ifromfile.

I suggest you could create a new viewmodel for this api method which contains the ifromfile like below:

```
public class EmployeeDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Wtest { get; set; }

    public IFormFile file { get; set; }
}
```

api:

```
    [HttpPost("AddEmployee")]
    public IActionResult AddEmployee([FromForm]EmployeeDto employee)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```